# Ghostscript How to watermark one special page of a postscript document?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I already add watermark (or image) in every page of a .ps document by below command and gs script.

```
[root@localhost ~]#gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=watermarked.ps mark.ps doc_test.ps
```

content of mark.ps:

```
<<
/EndPage
{
  2 eq { pop false }
  {
    gsave
    /STSong-Light-UniGB-UTF8-H findfont 30 scalefont setfont
    newpath
    .87 setgray
    260 50 moveto 30 rotate
    (test 测试) false  charpath
    1 setlinewidth stroke
    grestore
    true
  } ifelse
} bind
>> setpagedevice
```

but I don't know how to specify a page to add watermark, example the .ps document is 12 pages long, I just want to add watermark on page 6, but I want the output file to contain all 12 pages document content and just page 6 has a watermark.
Does anyone Ghostscript expert know how to script this requirement?
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the input is PostScript you can use the number your program pops from the stack, because this is the count of pages executed so far.

If you look at the definition of EndPage in the PLRM (page 427 in the 3rd edition) you will see that the operand stack contains two numbers, a reason code on top and the count of previous showpage executions. You need to test the reason code first. If its 2, pop the count and return false. If it is not 2, then check the second number to see if its tha value that will trigger your page. If it is not then return true. If it is, then first execute your marking routine an dthen return true.

NB it looks to me like your program is leaving the count of showpage executions on the operand stack when the reason code is 2. THis is poor practice; if called often enough you could cause a stack overflow error. Its also legal for a program to leave operands on the stack during showpage, and use them after. If you leave somethign on the stack then it would mean that program retrieving the wrong objects.

Unfortunately, when the input is PDF, the Ghostscript PDF interpreter executes a setpagedevice on every page, and this resets the count to 0.

So when the input is PDF you need to modify your program to keep a count of pages it has encountered so far, so that you can check it and only activate when required. Give it a unique name and store it in userdict, incrememnt it on every execution of EndPage, and run the marking part of the program only when it reaches a particular value.

PostScript **is** a programming language......

Comment: thanks for your help, I use below script to add watermark on one page,
<<
   /EndPage
   {
     2 eq { pop false }
     {
         7 ne {
         gsave
         /STSong-Light-UniGB-UTF8-H findfont 30 scalefont setfont
         newpath
         .87 setgray
         260 50 moveto 30 rotate
         (test 测试) false  charpath
         1 setlinewidth stroke
         grestore
         true
         } {true} ifelse
     } ifelse
   } bind
>>  setpagedevice
it can work on version 9.07, but when i change gs to 9.22 it can not work normal.

Comment: Under gs 9.22, if I change the number to 0, all pages are watermarked, change the number to other, all pages are not added.Is this syntax difference due to the version upgrade? Do you know where to find the usage of the syntax,I had never learned this grammar before, and there was little information available on the Internet. thanks very much.  Correct the syntax, above (7 ne) to (7 eq), above  comment can not be changed, I can only correct it here.

Comment: You've missed my point. You can't simply change that number because that's the **reason code**, the count of pages so far is the number above that on the operand stack which is popped by the 'pop' when the reason code is 2. The PostScript language is documented in teh PostScript Language Reference Manual which can be downloaded somewhere (it keeps moving) on the Adobe web site. You're going to need to read that if you want to program in PostScript.

Comment: Your first comment looks like it shoudl work, if it does not then the first thing to try is to use the current version of Ghostscript, which is 9.26 (9.27 will be due for release in a few weeks). If that doesn't work, then you should probably raise a bug report, but note that you will need to be able to supply an example input file.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll do some more tests tomorrow to verify it in detail.You are very nice.

Comment: Hi KenS, I have a new doubt, the systems with questionable functionality have no file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Init/cidfmap by default. and they can not support command .runlibfileifexists, does the new version removed this command? I had download source 9.22 and compile it, then I use new gs to process documents, the document can be processed correctly. Do you think the issue is my local configuration? thanks a lot again.

Comment: The default behaviour for Ghostscript is to use a ROM file system (ie the files are included in the binary). However you can still tell Ghostscript to use fiels from disk by adding the -I parameter, and pointing it to the files on disk. You shoudl not use internal PostScript oeprators like .runlibfileifexists. These are a security hole and are rapidly being removed. I can't really comment on your result with an old version of Ghostscript. However if your previous version was from a package then its entirely possible that the packager changed something which broke EndPage processing.